# Adding subscriber to interest group in list using mailchimp api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mailchimp

I'm using mailchimp in my application to send bulk emails to registered users. The application's front end is developed in angularjs / javascript and I don't have access to backend. While integrating mailchimp I've been successful to add users to list so far....But I want to add the user in the particular list as well as the interest group in it. I'm using `$http service` to hit a url which is in following format:

```
https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json?apikey=<my api key>&id=<list id>&email[email]=test@gmail.com&merge_vars[FNAME]=First&merge_vars[LNAME]=Last&merge_vars[MMERGE4]=Test 1&double_optin=false&send_welcome=false&merge_vars[MMERGE3]=First Last&merge_vars[GROUPINGS[14445[groups][51493]]]=true
```

This url allows me to add the user to my list but it doesn't add user in interest groups. I've searched for solution alot but all I could find is the solutions using php.

If anyone of you know any other solution for the above problem please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the subscriber to grouping `GROUP A` with options `OPTION A1` and `OPTION A2`, you must send the request like this,

```
merge_vars[groupings][0][name]=GROUP A // or merge_vars[groupings][0][id]=1234
merge_vars[groupings][0][groups][0]=OPTION A1
merge_vars[groupings][0][groups][1]=OPTION A2
```

If you want to add more grouping you could send like this,

```
merge_vars[groupings][0][name]=GROUP A
merge_vars[groupings][0][groups][0]=OPTION A1
merge_vars[groupings][0][groups][1]=OPTION A2
merge_vars[groupings][1][name]=GROUP B
merge_vars[groupings][1][groups][0]=OPTION B1
merge_vars[groupings][1][groups][1]=OPTION B2
```

So here you should send the parameters with requesting URL as like this,

```
https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json?apikey=<my api key>&id=<list id>&email[email]=test@gmail.com&merge_vars[FNAME]=First&merge_vars[LNAME]=Last&merge_vars[MMERGE4]=Test 1&double_optin=false&send_welcome=false&merge_vars[MMERGE3]=First Last&merge_vars[groupings][0][name]=GROUP A&merge_vars[groupings][0][groups][0]=OPTION A1&merge_vars[groupings][0][groups][1]=OPTION A2
```

Hope this helps. :)